# Binary coded message on a house in Catalonia

Tags: cipher, real

I found this inscription on a [wall of a house](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.4747676,1.934715,3a,75y,2.3h,124.32t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snc5Vs2NpsZVUUcK9YslxiA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) in town of Martorell, Catalonia, Spain. It looks rather modern and I think its creator ciphered some word / message / joke in it. I tried to lookup ASCII characters from these numbers but to no avail. What could it be?

```
10         0
  01    1011
   0    110
0111    0010
1001    1011
1101    0001
0010    0111
1001    1010
1       0101
        10 1
        0
        1
```

[image: Wall 1]
[image: Wall 2]

Comment: Looks like it has a barcode in it too

Comment: Are we sure it's not just random / artistic?

Comment: Yeah, it could be just random / artistic. I hope it's not.

Comment: I guess it's random, because if the code is position independently coded, then there's not enough room, because there's only 15 possiblities, but 26 letters ! Either it's coded, and written carefully, in a position dependant way (I doubt it), or its not mapping to letters, or it's random artistic, like the math equation you often see on pop science magazine, which are unreadable and nonsense.

Comment: 12 Rows mean 6 ASCII characters, extrapolating the missing ones may provide some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some search on Google and came across [this website](http://www.poma.cat/cat/projectes/habitatge/plurifamiliar-martorell.html).

Unfortunately, it's in Spanish... Any Spaniards here? :)

Copying and pasting the description from the website into Google translator doesn't give much information about the inscription, only this:

> However, we opted for a reinterpretation and renewal of the ornamental motifs, giving clues to the period of construction, determined by the technology of the "zeros and ones".

So I would think it's random / artistic.

Also, i think [this is](http://www.perepuigarquitecte.com/index.php?lang=eng) the architect's personal website, so you can contact him! :)

Comment: Great job! Though it's not in Spanish, it's in **Catalan.**